# Android Maps API - FIngerprint BUg

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fingerprint-api

I have create android application with google maps android api key, i have changed the api in manifest and restricted the api on application with fingerprint and packagename, the application manifest say fingerprint:

19:96:C0:DF:1B:E0:34:2C:2D:1C:08:23:3D:03:CA:13:65:76:B9:57

[image]

[image]

And i have used this for locking application.

But after application submitting to google play store maps not working and log say another fingerprint:

[image]

If istall signed apk before submitting to store i have another fingerprint:

BF:C5:88:AC:C1:79:D6:B1:26:02:8D:3F:BD:E8:C7:75:ED:32:B4:10

So why i have 3 fingerprint with same application? How to restrict this api to my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now days Google play store generate own signed SH1 key, So pls you add google play generated SH1 key at google console api, where you register your app at google console app.

Comment: Ahhh here... https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?account=#KeyManagementPlace

Thanks so much!